# Equivalent of pgpool-II for MySQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql, load-balancing, connection-pooling, pgpool

Is there any tools which is equivalent to **[pgpool-II](http://pgpool.projects.postgresql.org/pgpool-II/doc/pgpool-en.html)** (which is for PostgreSQL) for MySQL db?

Of particular importance for me is the feature - Load Balalce

## Load Balance

> If a database is replicated, executing
>   a SELECT query on any server will
>   return the same result. pgpool-II
>   takes an advantage of the replication
>   feature to reduce the load on each
>   PostgreSQL server by distributing
>   SELECT queries among multiple servers,
>   improving system's overall throughput.
>   At best, performance improves
>   proportionally to the number of
>   PostgreSQL servers. Load balance works
>   best in a situation where there are a
>   lot of users executing many queries at
>   the same time.